# How to set the build description based on console output

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Based on this [article](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/220860347-How-to-set-build-name-in-Pipeline-job-), you can set the build description in Jenkinsfile like so:

```
node {
    currentBuild.displayName = "fooName"
    currentBuild.description = "fooDescription"
}
```

But with the hudson.plugins.descriptionsetter.DescriptionSetterPublisher plugin, you can do set the build description via a regex based on the build output:

[image: Set Build Description]

How do you set the build description in a Jenkinsfile via a regex based on the build output?

For example, here is my Jenkinsfile.  I'm not sure what to put in the PostBuild section to set the build description. I know the regex is ^Jenkins Description: (.*).  So if the output is something like:

`blah
blah
blah
Jenkins Description: My super build
blah
blah
blah`

The description of the build should be "My super build"

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'my_node' }
  // Run the the stages:
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        sh "deploy/jenkins_build.sh"
      }
    }
  }
  post {
        always {
            SET_BUILD_DESCRIPTION_REGEX_BASED_ON_BUILD_OUTPUT
        }
}
```

Comment: I also put the same question on the ticket to support PipeLine for this plugin: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-38132

Comment: Are you just asking for the regex? Can you post the build output?